# "Дом крепкий как скала." Где поставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

**Дом крепкий как скала.**

Где нужна запятая в данном предложении, после слова *дом* или после слова *крепкий*?

Answer (score 3):

*Дом крепкий, как скала.*
Если это двусоставное предложение, то обособляем сравнительный оборот.

Если односоставное назывное, то после слова *дом* тоже ставим запятую — обособление определения, стоящего после определяемого слова.
*Дом, крепкий, как скала*.

Возможно и с одной запятой после слова *дом*, если счесть, что сравнительный оборот превратился во фразеологизм, но пока значение сравнения здесь достаточно ярко. Я бы предпочла первый вариант, если в контексте это двусоставное предложение, не парцеллированная конструкция.

Answer (score 3):

Оборот ***как скала*** может обособляться или не обособляться в различных конструкциях. Это может зависеть от того, к чему относится сравнение (к предмету или признаку): ***крепкий как скала*** или ***дом как скала***.

**Дом крЕпкий,  как скАла.** Другими словами: ***дом как скала,*** такой же крепкий.

Сравнить: ДОм, **крепкий как скАла**, был построен еще  прошлом веке. В обособленном обороте сравнение относится к прилагательному, **выполняя функцию наречия** (очень крепкий).

В тоже время сравнение может обособляться от прилагательного, а также может не включаться  в распространенный обособленный оборот на основе прилагательного **при отсутствии тесной связи.**

Все варианты **можно проверить с помощью интонационного ударения.**

**Примеры**

Такой суровый Баев, **неприступный как скалА,** и на тебе — семейный очаг, игры в королей и капусту. [Екатерина Завершнева. Высотка (2012)]

Он твердил это себе постоянно,  чтобы стойкое состояние «консервации духа»...оставалось **несокрушИмым, как скалА,** а иначе хана… [Дина Рубина. Русская канарейка. Блудный сын (2014)]

Но тот стоял на месте, **прямой и твЁрдый, как скалА,** лицо его тоже словно окаменело, и Артем опять ощутил недавнее желание убить живого человека. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]